# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request in C# (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to enable the operator to reach the function by debugging in .NET CORE
in C#,
and I get an error like this:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request
> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type ;PlatformWebApi.Controllers.Order.IOrderHelp& while attempting to activate
> PlatformWebApi.Controllers.Order.OrderApi
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)

The code is:

OrderApi.cs

```cs
namespace PlatformWebApi.Controllers.Order
{
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public class OrderApi: Controller
    {
        public Log log = new Log();
        private readonly WebOptions _webOption;
        private IWebApiHelp _WebApiHelp;
        private ISapFunction _sapFunction;
        private readonly  IOrderHelp _orderHelp;
        public OrderApi(IOptions<WebOptions> myConfiguration,
           IWebApiHelp WebApiHelp,
           ISapFunction SapFunction,
           IOrderHelp OrderHelp)
        {
            _webOption = myConfiguration.Value;
            _WebApiHelp = WebApiHelp;
            _orderHelp = OrderHelp;
            _sapFunction = SapFunction;
        }
        [HttpPost(ApiRoutes.Order.AddUpdateOrder)]
        [Consumes("application/xml", "application/json")]
        //OrderXml.OrderDetails
        public ResponseData AddUpdateOrder([FromBody] OrderXml.OrderDetails xmlString)
        {
            ResponseData oRes = _orderHelp.Add_updateOrder(xmlString);
            return oRes;//Json(oRes);
        }
        //[HttpPost(ApiRoutes.Order.UpdateOrderStep)]
        //[Consumes("application/xml", "application/json")]

        //public ResponseData UpdateOrderStep([FromBody]string xmlString)
        //{
        //    ResponseData oRes = _orderHelp.Update_OrderStep(xmlString);
        //    return oRes;//Json(oRes);
        //}

    }
}
```

IOrderHelp.cs

```cs
namespace PlatformWebApi.Controllers.Order
{
    public interface IOrderHelp
    {
        ResponseData Add_updateOrder(OrderXml.OrderDetails xmlString);
    
    }
}
```

OrderHelp.cs:

```
public class OrderHelp :IOrderHelp
    {
        // _SAPConnectionHelp _SAPConnectionHelp = new _SAPConnectionHelp();
       

        string error = "";
        public Log log = new Log();
        private readonly WebOptions _webOption;
        private IWebApiHelp _WebApiHelp;
        private ISapFunction _sapFunction;
        private ISAPConnectionHelp _SAPConnectionHelp;


        public OrderHelp(IOptions<WebOptions> myConfiguration,
           IWebApiHelp WebApiHelp,
           ISapFunction SapFunction,
           ISAPConnectionHelp SAPConnectionHelp)
        {
            _webOption = myConfiguration.Value;
            _WebApiHelp = WebApiHelp;
            _sapFunction = SapFunction;
            _SAPConnectionHelp = SAPConnectionHelp;
        }
 public ResponseData Add_updateOrder(OrderXml.OrderDetails xmlString)
        {
            string sErrorMsg = "";
            //  //CustomLog.MyLogger.info("----------STRART NewOrder");
            int DocEntry = 0, res = 0;
            List<ResponseKeys> oListResponseKeys = new List<ResponseKeys>();
            ResponseData oResponseData = new ResponseData();

            SAPbobsCOM.Documents oOrder = (Documents)_SAPConnectionHelp.GetCompany().GetBusinessObject(BoObjectTypes.oOrders);
....
}
}
```

Would appreciate help

I wanted to reach the function by debugging,
and in fact I encountered an error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request
> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type ;PlatformWebApi.Controllers.Order.IOrderHelp& while attempting to activate
> PlatformWebApi.Controllers.Order.OrderApi
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)

Comment: You need to register IOrderHelp in your dependency container

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the problem you are facing depends on Dependency Injection used within your controller.

You declare your filed like this:
`private readonly  IOrderHelp _orderHelp;`

Then in your case i would check if in your `Program.cs` you have added the correct interface and class to dependecy injection. It could be something like this:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IOrderHelp, OrderHelp>();
```

Where in this case `IOrderHelp` is the interface and the `OrderHelp` is the class implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Hey it looks like you are missing the dependency injection for your service. Go to the Programm.cs and add :

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IOrderHelper,OrderHelper>();
```

Now you can use your service in your classes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Answer (score 1):

it's look like you are missing the DI (Dependency Injection) for You're
`OrderHelp`.

to Fix This Problem. Go To `Program.cs` and Add This Line:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IOrderHelp, OrderHelp>(); (.Net 6 +)
```

beware!, if you're `OrderHelp` class uses Scoped Services Like DbContext, Add Service As Scoped not Singleton To Fix that Replace `AddScoped` Instead `AddSingleton`.